# Scene is darker when playing in editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a menu scene which goes to the game scene by calling `SceneManager.LoadScene` method.

Everything is alright when I build the game and play (or play in editor starting from the game scene).

But when I play the game in the editor (starting from the menu) the game scene is darker than usual.

That's not hurting me, but I'm curious to know the reason.

By the way, I have only the one default directional light which unity creates.

Screenshots:

**Normal (Playing the game after build)**
[image: Normal]

**Darker (Playing the game in editor starting from the menu scene)**
[image: Darker]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to disable the contious light baking.

In order to do so in Unity 2017.1, go to `Window` -> `Lighting` -> `Settings` and uncheck `Auto Generate` at the bottom of the window. Then, press `Generate Lightning` to bake the lighting once manually.

Note that if you add more lights or make some changes, you have to bake the lightmap again.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But why it works after the build and not in the editor?

Comment: Because Unity bakes the lightning before compiling. The auto baking is usefull when you are currently editing your scene, but it takes some resources, baking the lightning stores the lightning information once for all in order to be more efficient when you play.

Comment: but is it necessary to bake the light manually when you are using only realtime lights?

Comment: You can try by yourself, disable auto light baking, put a real time sun in your scene with a plane, change the color / orientation / intensity of the sun and see if you have to manually bake again ;)